# On change to preserve original text in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am looking to try and write some code that checks whether a value has been changed. If it has, I want it to revert it back to its old value when focused out. Here's what I have, but I find this doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var Foo = '101';

   $("#cfs_i9_cf9").focusin(function(){
      Foo = (this).value;
   });

   $("#cfs_i9_cf9").on('change', function(){
      $("#cfs_i9_cf9").attr('value', Math.round(Foo*100)/100);
   });

});
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You overwrite `Foo`. Take another `var old = 101;`.

Comment: Why change the value of Foo at all if you want to keep it? Just define another variable

Comment: Why don't you make the field readonly then?

Comment: I can't make it read only because of the fact I'm editing forms within a website which has a very prescriptive options. As for changing the value, to be honest the 101 can be ignored, I want "Foo" to represent the value when I focus in, then utilise it to keep that value when I focus out in case someone attempts to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Restore the value on `focusout` instead of `change`

This way the value is restored when the user actually exits the field, not during typing.

Furthermore use jQuery's `val` to (re)set the field value;

```
$("#cfs_i9_cf9").on('focusout', function(){
    $("#cfs_i9_cf9").val(Math.round(Foo*100)/100);
});
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fo29hoa2/)

Finally ensure `#cfs_i9_cf9` is actually the `<input>` element.

Comment: Thanks for this, it doesn't seem to restore the value however? It simply keeps what it changed to?

Comment: @jcwp87 - yes the code needed another minor fix. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize jQuery's [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method to store the old value and restore it on focus out. This way, you can totally eliminate the need of any extra variable.

```
$("#cfs_i9_cf9")
  .focusin(function(){
    $(this).data('old_value', this.value);
  })
  .focusout(function() {
    var oldValue = $(this).data('old_value');

    if (!!oldValue) {
      this.value = oldValue;
    }
  });
```

Please note that I've just assigned the old value to the field on focus out. You can modify the logic as per your need.